# Is there a way to map unknown geom/shapefile/multipolygon to a known multipolygon table?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, shapefile, multipolygons

I have two tables, `Table_A`:

| ID | known_multipolygon |
| --- | --- |
| A | Philadelphia |
| B | Baltimore |
| C | Charlotte |

And `Table_B`:

| ID | unknown_multipolygon |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | unknown_polygon_A |
| 2 | unknown_polygon_B |
| 3 | unknown_polygon_C |

`Table_A` is essentially a reference table, each row is a known multipolygon of an area. `Table_B`, however, is an unknown combination of multipolygons that could be either a single location, e.g., `unknown_polygon_A` could be `Charlotte`, or a combination of multipolygons, e.g., `unknown_polygon_A` could be `Philadelphia` + `Baltimore`. The problem is, I do not know what `known_multipolygon`, or combination of `known_polygon`, make up the `Table_B.unknown_multipolygon`. Is there a way to determine the polygons that make up `Table_B.unknown_multipolygon`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`st_contains`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) to join the two tables:

```sql
SELECT b.ID as unknown_id,
       a.ID as known_id
FROM Table_B b
 JOIN Table_A a
   ON st_contains(b.geometry, a.geometry);
```

Comment: Thanks! But that will only identify the unknown if there is exactly one polygon match within the in unknown polygon column. As I mentioned in the question, the unknown column could also be a combination of 2 (or 3) polygon areas.

Comment: @MarkelleFultz no, it should return one row per matching source